# How to update Tinymce's existing plug-ins and get them working in Tinymce 2.2

Tags: tinymce

I need to update one of the Tinymce's existing plug-in for which i made few updates in editor_plugin.js, i made updates and refreshed browser but the code updates are not reflecting. Can anybody please share how to update existing plugins in tinymce and get them working.

Please note that i'am using Tinymce version 2.2.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you mean is you need to downgrade a recent tinymce plugin?
In order to get your code used you need to make sure to place your code inside `editor_plugin_src.js` as well. THe usage of files depends of the tinymce file you have included usable are `tiny_mce.js` and `tiny_mce_dev.js`. The dev-version is used to debug easier and will load the `editor_plugin_src.js` files.

Comment: Actually i need to update the clipboard data before pasting it in textarea,i thought that i can access that data in TinyMCE_paste_clipboardHTML() method in paste plug-in.I made updates in this method but these are not reflecting.I think this plugin is not used in version(2.2) that i have.I need to remove a `<DIV>` with a particular Id from the clipboard data before the data is pasted in the textarea. Also, i tried using window.getClipboardData("Text") on paste event,but this method returns only text data and not the HTML tags,so i don't get the `<DIV>` here. Pls help..

Comment: In case the paste plugin is not available in Version2 i don't knwo what to do. What about updating tinymce. Old versions like v2 won't work well with newer browsers anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions..This issue is resolved now..i set the this attribute paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste to true and it worked..